# Error of Shape Using Conv1D in Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I have troubles using Conv1D as an input layer in Sequential NN with Keras.
Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np    
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D    
from keras.models import Sequential    
from keras.optimizers import Adam    

conv1d = Conv1D(input_shape=(None, 16), kernel_size=2, filters=2)    

model = Sequential()    
model.add(conv1d)    
model.compile(loss="logcosh", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))    

x_train = np.zeros((32, 16, 1))    
y_train = np.zeros((32, 16, 1))    

print(x_train.shape)    

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=4, epochs=20)
```

Here is the error. I have tried multiple things but none of them helped me to resolve the issue.

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_47_input to have shape (None, 16) but got array with shape (16, 1)

Answer (score 1):

`Conv1D` expects the inputs to have the shape `(batch_size, steps, input_dim)`.

Based on the shape of your training data, you have max length 16 and input dimensionality just 1. Is that what you need?

If so, then the input shape can be specified either as `(16, 1)` (length is always 16) or `(None, 1)` (dynamic length).

If you meant to define sequences of length 1 and dimensionality 16, then you need a different shape of the training data:

```
x_train = np.zeros((32, 1, 16))
y_train = np.zeros((32, 1, 16))
```

Comment: Still not working. error is : Error when checking target: expected conv1d_52 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (1, 16)

Comment: Your final layer is a 1d-convolution which produces a 2-dimensional vector for each step. Keras is telling you that the shape of your targets (`y_train`) is incompatible with the output shape of the final layer.

Comment: I don't see where you're going with this model but the simplest way to "fix" it would be for the number of output filters to match the dimensionality of the output, i.e.:

`conv1d = Conv1D(input_shape=(None, 16), kernel_size=2, filters=16)`

Comment: I Have a dataset of 32 vectors of length 16. I would like to put them in a convNN. The code qbove is just a snippet of the Neural Net. I add a few layers afterwrds. But since the First Layer don't work I am stuck here. I have tried to add a dimension as shown above. I've tried to arange the dimentiality in every way but again and again I get some errors. I can't Find a way to move on. Maybe if I try exchange different layer it could help but it would also change the averall goal of the algorithm, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution using flatten function and a dense layer and it worked

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Dense, MaxPool1D, Flatten, Input

conv1d = Conv1D(input_shape=(16,1), kernel_size=2, filters=2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(conv1d)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss="cosine_proximity",metrics=["accuracy"])

x_train = np.zeros((32,16,1))
y_train = np.zeros((32,16))

print(x_train.shape)
print()

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=4, epochs=20)
```